# Eval Operator in Ruby for Refactoring

Tags: ruby, selenium, assert

We were refactoring our automation scripts written using Ruby and Selenium and had a discussion about using eval operator in ruby to reduce code. Here is what we have

I have a method 'ValidateViewPageElements' that is a getter method that gets all the values from the web ui and compare it against our xml data repository. I also have a CustomAssertion class I have written that contains a method 'verify_browser_element' that takes the actual value (value of the web object) and expected value and does basically what an assert should do. If values match it will log success and if they do not it will log an error.

```
def validateViewPageElements()
  CustomAssertion.verify_browser_element_value(complete_field.exists?, false)
  CustomAssertion.verify_browser_element_value(editdarrecord_field.exists?, false)
  CustomAssertion.verify_browser_element_value(addvehicle_field.exists?, false)
end
```

One of the code review comment to refactor the above was to use eval expression and do the something like the following to minimize code

```
def validateViewPageElements()
  array = ["complete_field","editdarrecord_field","addvehicle_field"]
  for i in 0..array.length
    CustomAssertion.verify_browser_element_value(eval array[i].value, false)
  end
end
```

I have read a few articles about justifying the use of eval statements and its cons, but is there a need in the above case to be used. My suggestions to not use the above refactoring was the following. Eval statement creates a new byte everytime it is used. 2. It does not give clarity to developer on what the method is defined for. 3. Introducing loops to minimize lines of code is not very favorable. 4. Difficult to change expected values in loop as they all have to be the same.

Are there any other reason why eval should be avoided in the above case or am I wrong in my assumptions and that it is a good practice to use it in above case example to reduce 15 assertion lines to 5 lines of code? Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `for` loop in Ruby is just plain weird and using `eval` for something so simple makes me question your reviewer's sanity. You usually use iterators instead of loops in Ruby and you can use [`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) instead of `eval`:

```
def validateViewPageElements()
  %w[complete_field editdarrecord_field addvehicle_field].each do |m|
    CustomAssertion.verify_browser_element_value(send(m).value, false)
  end
end
```

I also switched to `%w[]` for the array of strings, less quote-noise that way.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
def validateViewPageElements()
  [complete_field, editarrecord_field, addvehicle_field].each {|field| CustomAssertion.verify_browser_element_value(field.exists?, false)}  
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that is one way to reduce all the lines that assert the expected value to be false without using Eval expression. The only caveat here will be if tomorrow a field expe

Comment: expected value changes from false to true then it will require that a few fields be part of the array comparison and one another one is a separate assert. Thanks. Do you know some good reason as to avoid Eval expression?